# Doing multi threaded unit test with testng

Tags: java, junit, testng

I am learning doing unit testing with TestNg. I wanted to pass unique value of variable "val" to every thread from thread pool but it is not picking it up.

here the testng class:

```
public class NewTest {

    int val = 0;

  /*@Test(dataProvider = "dp")
  public void f(Integer n, String s) {
  }*/
  @BeforeMethod
  public void beforeMethod() {
      long id = Thread.currentThread().getId();
      System.out.println("beforeMethod. Thread id is: " + id);



  }

  @AfterMethod
  public void afterMethod() {/*
      long id = Thread.currentThread().getId();
      System.out.println("After test-method. Thread id is: " + id);*/
  }


  @DataProvider
  public Object[][] dp() {
    return new Object[][] {
      new Object[] { 1, "a" },
      new Object[] { 2, "b" },
    };
  }
  @BeforeClass
  public void beforeClass() {

  }

  @AfterClass
  public void afterClass() {
  }

  @BeforeTest
  public void beforeTest() {
      val++;
  }

  @AfterTest
  public void afterTest() {
  }

  @BeforeSuite
  public void beforeSuite() {
  }

  @AfterSuite
  public void afterSuite() {
  }

  @Test(threadPoolSize = 5, invocationCount = 5, timeOut = 1000)
  public void methodOne(){
      System.out.println("Value of val from MethodOne::"+val);
  }
}
```

and output:

> [ThreadUtil] Starting executor timeOut:1000ms workers:5
>   threadPoolSize:5 beforeMethod. Thread id is: 15 beforeMethod. Thread
>   id is: 12 beforeMethod. Thread id is: 14 beforeMethod. Thread id is:
>   13 beforeMethod. Thread id is: 16 Value of val from MethodOne::1 Value
>   of val from MethodOne::1 Value of val from MethodOne::1 Value of val
>   from MethodOne::1 Value of val from MethodOne::1 PASSED: methodOne
>   PASSED: methodOne PASSED: methodOne PASSED: methodOne PASSED:
>   methodOne
>
> ===============================================
>       Default test
>
> ## Tests run: 5, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
>
> ## =============================================== Default suite Total tests run: 5, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
>
> [TestNG] Time taken by [FailedReporter passed=0 failed=0 skipped=0]: 1
>   ms [TestNG] Time taken by
>   org.testng.reporters.SuiteHTMLReporter@3159c4b8: 50 ms [TestNG] Time
>   taken by org.testng.reporters.JUnitReportReporter@6adede5: 7 ms
>   [TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.XMLReporter@64bf3bbf: 9 ms
>   [TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.jq.Main@1d16f93d: 40 ms
>   [TestNG] Time taken by
>   org.testng.reporters.EmailableReporter2@5bc79255: 4 ms

Answer (score 0):

Be careful: `@BeforeTest` is not `@BeforeMethod` (`@BeforeSuite` -> `@BeforeTest` -> `@BeforeClass` -> `@BeforeMethod`, and `@BeforeGroup` which a specific one).

Then, `@BeforeTest` is call only once by `<test>`: in your sample, only once and `val` is always 1.

Comment: I changed increment step in @BeforeMethod , but still I am getting the same output.

Comment: Could you update your question with the updated sample ?

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage `ThreadLocal` as shown below : (But please remember that TestNG guarantees that only `@BeforeMethod` > `@Test` > `@AfterMethod` annotated methods would run on the same thread.

```
public class NewTest {
    private static ThreadLocal<Long> val = new ThreadLocal<>();

    @BeforeMethod
    public void beforeMethod() {
        long id = Thread.currentThread().getId();
        val.set(id);
        printer("beforeMethod");
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void afterMethod() {
        printer("afterMethod");
        //usage of thread locale done. Lets reset it.
        val.set(null);
    }

    @Test (threadPoolSize = 5, invocationCount = 5, timeOut = 1000)
    public void methodOne() {
        printer("methodOne");
    }

    private static void printer(String prefix) {
        System.err.println("Thread ID in the method " + prefix + "() is " + val.get());
    }
}
```